# R: cmdscale: need to use dissimilaritymatrix?

Tags: r, dimensionality-reduction

After some testing, it seems that we can feed either dissimilarity or similarity matrices to cmdscale (apparently the function detects when it is a similarity so it will take 1 - the matrix).

Therefore

```
F=mysimilarityMatrix
mds <- stats::cmdscale(F, k= 2)
```

is equal to

```
F=1-mysimilarityMatrix
mds <- stats::cmdscale(F, k= 2)
```

I would just want confirmation, since the function does not clarify this.
Thanks!

Comment: As you say, the behavior is not documented, therefore the safe approach would be to convert the matrix yourself, but you could also look at the source code for `cmdscale` to see. The function could only detect that it was a similarity matrix if the full symmetric matrix was passed to the function instead of a `dist` object created using a similarity measure.

Comment: I can't test it at the moment, but wouldn't the cmdscale apply squareform to the vector to reconstruct the full matrix?

Comment: Sure but it will assume the diagonal is 0 which is not the case for a similarity matrix.